Why does the string "8000423E-1670872784" equal "8000427E-1689194367"?
What's going on here?  Why does the first check return true?  What's the difference between the first check and the third?
php > var_dump("8000423E-1670872784" == "8000427E-1689194367");
bool(true)
php > var_dump("8000423E-1670872784" === "8000427E-1689194367");
bool(false)
php > var_dump("8000423A-1670872784" == "8000427A-1689194367");
bool(false)


They're being treated as numbers with the double equals, but as strings with the triple equals: "If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the comparison performed numerically." Check this answer for more

I added the third check to the question.  I think my question is different because the my strings have a letter and a dash.

Theyre still numbers, just in scientific notation. 8000423E-1670872784 is the same as 8000423 x 10 ^ -1670872784. Because of floating point precision, it's treated as zero.

I realize now that PHP may be interpreting the string as scientific notation.  That's why the third check returns false.

Yes, thanks.  I didn't consider scientific notation at first.  It seems to me like that should be an answer and that the questions are different.

You're being hit by three things at once: "numerical strings", scientific notation, and floating-point imprecision.
Numerical Strings
PHP tries to compare strings as numbers when using double equals, if it can successfully parse them into numbers. PHP calls these "numeric strings". How nice of PHP to do that for you! Although... 8000423E-1670872784 doesn't seem like it can be a number... after all, we have "E" and "-" in there, so what gives?
Scientific Notation
For convenience, really large numbers can be written using scientific notation: 9.2x10^8 would be 920,000,000. Computers support a shorthand form for scientific notation: "9.2e8" (ever seen "E" on calculators before?), and PHP's number-parsing supports this. This is generally convenient, but can lead to some things being interpreted as numeric strings when they weren't.
That explains the E, but what about the "-"? It's just a negative sign for the exponent. 9.2e-8 would be equivalent to 9.2x10^-8, or 0.000000092. Negative moves the decimal to the left, positive moves it to the right.
In your case, so many things happened to hold true for your string to be a numeric string:

if your strings contained any letter other than a single "E", they wouldn't be numeric
if you had more than a single "-" in your strings, they wouldn't be numeric.
if your "-" wasn't directly after the only "E" (where a sign makes sense in a number), your strings wouldn't be numeric

Floating-point (im)precision
Alright, now we know that these strings are being compared to one another as numbers. But even so, why would they be equal? Their exponents differ by over 18 million, after all...
Well, computers have limited storage space, and so the cutoff has to be somewhere. PHP stores these numbers as IEEE-754 floating-point numbers, and because of the limited precision that floating point numbers have, both are rounded to just be zero. (var_dump("8000423E-1670872784" == "0"); also returns bool(true))

What about cases 2 and 3?
Your second case, var_dump("8000423E-1670872784" === "8000427E-1689194367");, uses triple equals instead of double equals; meaning that it's treated as a proper string comparison, even though they're "numeric strings".
Your third case, var_dump("8000423A-1670872784" == "8000427A-1689194367");, cannot be parsed into numbers. "A" has no meaning here, parsing fails, and the strings are instead compared as normal strings instead of numbers.
